# What is the name of this common metal tubing?

Tags: enclosure

I see tubing used all over the place in machines, but I do not know what it is called. The cross section looks somewhat like this drawn picture. Can someone clue me in on it?

[image: Tubing]

Comment: très artistique! :-)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is was never about electronic design, and keeps attracting spam making it not simply harmlessly off topic, but actively a detriment to the site.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: moving it to the likes of Engineering.SE might be a better option, as this question long predates the existence of many of the now better venues for this question. Perhaps a mod can migrate as the close options indicate it's otherwise too old.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Structural aluminum extrusion:

http://www.8020.net/

http://www.minitecframing.com/ (my favorite)

http://www13.boschrexroth-us.com/framing_shop/

Comment: There are many manufacturers and suppliers. It is commonly used in mocking up industrial fixtures and even on production machinery.

Answer (score 9):

[T-Slot](http://www.tslots.com/) is the name I recognize it as. I assume there are also generic T-slotted aluminum extrusions available as well.

Answer (score 6):

While you're probably looking at "full size" structural extruded aluminum T-slot,
for completeness I'm going to mention miniature versions:

MakerBeam is developing the Mini-T standard for open source hardware. http://www.makerbeam.com/

MicroRAX a light weight mini T-Slot building kit.
http://www.microrax.com/

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Would Fischertechnik not do the job?
[image: Fischertechnik]